# when is the Spring Framework 4 EOL?

Tags: spring, end-of-life

I wanna know about the EOL of Spring framework4 version.
 I searched many things, but they are all different.
 (Results what I found are ~ 2019. 12. 31 or ~2020. 12. 31)

If I can take some latest updates, I`m very happy about that :-)
 Thanks.

Comment: Where did you found this dates? Can you share links?

Comment: Spring-Boot 1 goes EOL on Aug 1st, 2019. See also https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019 . I assume that it will also hint towards an EOL of Spring 4 in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current plans for EOL of the different Spring Versions can be found at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions

For Spring 4.3 it's "extended maintenance until 2020"